# Javascript Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div which has a max height and a scroll bar on it.

In the div is a large list of items

```
(<ul><li></li>...</ul>)
```

How do i in JavaScript make it so on page load it scrolls the div so that it is showing a certain list item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this jquery plugin.

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do with the scrollTop property of div. 
for an example.

```
div.scrollTop=200
```

you can make a function and call it on `onload` event.
may help you.

Thanks.